# GTest's EXPECT_EQ giving undefined reference to error

Tags: c++, googletest

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(T (&arr)[N]){
 return N; 
}

template<int N>
struct ArrayParam {
  static const int _length = N;
  int _arr[N];
};

ArrayParam<3> ap1 = {{1,2,3}};
//ArrayParam<4> ap2 = {{1,2,3,4}};

class ParamTest: public ::testing::TestWithParam<ArrayParam<3>>{};

TEST_P(ParamTest, SizeTest){
  ArrayParam<3> param = GetParam();

  printf("\nparam._length == %d\n",param._length); //OK
  printf("\nValue2 == %d\n",ArrayParam<3>::_length); //OK

  //EXPECT_EQ(param._length,getSize(param._arr)); //NOT OK
  //EXPECT_EQ(3,param._length); // NOT OK
  EXPECT_EQ(3,sizeof(param._arr)/sizeof(int)); //OK

}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ArraySize,ParamTest,testing::Values(ap1));
```

Does someone know why EXPECT_EQ doesn't work as printf when I try to access `_length`?

My ultimate goal is to write a single test for various `ArrayParam<T>` instance objects such as `ArrayParam<4> ap2`, `ArrayParam<5> ap3`, and so on.

**Error I'm getting:**

~/tests.cpp.o: In function `ParamTest_SizeTest_Test::TestBody()': ~/tests.cpp: undefined reference to`ArrayParam<3>::_length' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Why not use `std::array`? It's doing precisely what you're trying to do with `ArrayParam`

Comment: Please give us the full error error message as well.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it isn't the same as a `std::array`, because `_length` is static. From my experience with Google test, whether or not something is static can be a factor in determining what's possible and what isn't.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that's a good question. Have you tried it both ways?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I want to find out why this implementation doesn't work and what it lacks that std:array has to make that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

In general, static data members in C++ require definition outside of the class, like this:

```
struct A {
static int myInt;
};
A::myInt; //doesn't even have to be initialized
```

Const and non-volatile members are special, as can be seen [in the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members). They can be initialized with any constant expression inside the class body:

```
struct A {
static const int myInt = 1;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << A::myInt;
}
```

But, there is one exception to this rule (from the same paragraph in cppreference, emphasis mine):

> **If a const** [non-inline (since C++17)] **static data member** [or a constexpr
>   static data member (since C++11)] **is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), a definition at
>   namespace scope is still required**, but it cannot have an initializer.
>   This definition is deprecated for constexpr data members (since
>   C++17).

odr-used is explained as such (emphasis mine):

> Informally, an object is odr-used if its value is **read (unless it is a
>   compile time constant)** or **written**, **its address is taken**, **or a
>   reference is bound to it**; a reference is odr-used if it is used and
>   its referent is not known at compile time; and a function is odr-used
>   if a function call to it is made or its address is taken. If an
>   object, a reference or a function is odr-used, its definition must
>   exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is usually a
>   link-time error.

This is exactly what happens here. `EXPECT_EQ` takes parameters by `const T&`, i.e. **binds a reference** to this type. And since a reference is bound to `_length`, it makes it `odr-used` and requires an out-of-class member definition.

`odr-used` exception doesn't apply to `printf`, because `printf` (being a C function) doesn't take a reference. It falls into "read (unless it is a compile time constant)" part of the definition. And since we have a compile time constant, everything works fine.

### Solution

If you are using C++17, it's as simple as changing `const` to `constexpr`:

```
template<int N>
struct ArrayParam<N> {
  static constexpr int _length = N; 
  int _arr[N];
};
```

C++17 standard made definition for `constexpr static` members at namespace scope *deprecated* (you not only don't have to use it, you actually shouldn't use it).

---

If you are not using C++17, you have to add a definition of this data member in the same namespace as the class:

```
template<int N>
struct ArrayParam<N> {
    static constexpr int _length = N; //const is fine as well
    int _arr[N];
 };
template<int N>
constexpr int ArrayParam<N>::_length;
```

This will allow you to use it with GoogleTest's `EXPECT_EQ`

---

As a side note, I'd like to recommend using `std::array` one more time. It's more readable and easily recognized by all C++ programmers.
As most standard containers, it's efficient and well written by people with great experience. And it was tested  and proven fine by countless programmers using that before you.

Comment: Thank you so much, clarified so many things. Also noted your suggestion about using std::array.